# Class declaration merging for an existing type

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to make use of [Declaration Merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to extend the exitsing **Chart** type in [@types/chart.js](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chart.js/index.d.ts).
The idea is to add a property.

What I've done so far is this (file.d.ts):

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
import { Tooltip } from './tooltip';

declare module 'Chart' {
    class Chart {
      pluginTooltips?: Tooltip[];
    }
}
```

Tooltip is coming from a custom .ts file.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong because the code that is using this new property does not compile:

> TS2339 Property 'pluginTooltips' does not exist on type Chart

The type definition file is constructed as the following:

```
declare class Chart {...}
...
export = Chart;
export as namespace Chart;
```

I guess the module declaration is wrong, but I can't find what to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with module augmentation is always to find exactly what you want to augment. In this case you may think you want to augment the `chart.js` module but if we look at the definitions we see `export as namespace Chart;` This is an export for an UMD module and it is actually exporting a global class as a module ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require#umd-modules)).

So the module is just referencing the global `Chart` class, this is what we really want to augment.

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
type Tooltip = {t: any}

declare global {
    interface Chart {
        pluginTooltips?: Tooltip[];
    }
}

let c = new Chart(null!, null!);

c.pluginTooltips;  // ok now
```

Comment: I still have the same issue. Isn't Chart a class? Should I import the module augmentation somehow?

Comment: @OlivierMATROT `Chart` is a class but when augmenting you merge a class with an interface, you can't have multiple class definitions. I can provide my working code if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would be glad if you provide your code.